# Improve SQL Server conditional join

Tags: sql-server

Is correct to put these conditional sentences in join statement in order to improve performance?

I just tried to use same code using one union and cross apply per condition used, but when I use the code in other queries, is too slow.

```
SELECT u2.fkPropertyID, u2.pkUnitId, u2.UnitCode, 
       u2.fkUnitViewID,u2.fkFloorPlanID, u2.fkCalendarTypeID
FROM dbo.tblUnit                u 
left join dbo.tblUnitGroup ug  ON ug.fkUnitLogicalID = u.pkUnitID
left JOIN dbo.tblUnit u2  on ((u2.fkUnitGroupID = u.pkUnitID and 
    u.ynPhyUnit = 0)                                             
    or
    (u2.pkUnitID = u.pkUnitID and u2.ynPhyUnit =1))
    or 
    (u2.pkUnitId = ug.fkUnitPhisicallID and u2.ynPhyUnit = 1)
where u.pkUnitId = 3806
```

Comment: Why are you using a left join and then only selecting columns from one of the tables that is part of the left join? Are you ok with returning rows with nothing but NULL? As for the performance issue here you would need to provide an execution plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
    and [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Hi, Seam this is my execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJF1G4UtS, my concern is about the cost on [CDRPRD].[dbo].[tblUnit].[tblUnit_idxUnitGroup] [u2]

Comment: tblUnit_idxUnitGroup isnt even part of your query;

Comment: So what is the problem? The execution plan seem to be using all index.

Comment: Hi Juan, is not a problem at all, I wondering if there is a way to re-write the code, the conditional Joins

Comment: Sure I can come up with 2 or 3 ways to rewrite this and achieve the same result. But it won't generate a better execution plan. It might be slightly less code and a little less confusing but in the end it would be the same thing.

Comment: Sean and Juan thank you for your time, I will investigate by my self too, Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here is one way you could rewrite this. I suspect if you look at the execution plan it will be identical.

```
SELECT u2.fkPropertyID
    , u2.pkUnitId
    , u2.UnitCode
    , u2.fkUnitViewID
    , u2.fkFloorPlanID
    , u2.fkCalendarTypeID
FROM dbo.tblUnit u 
left join dbo.tblUnitGroup ug  ON ug.fkUnitLogicalID = u.pkUnitID
left JOIN dbo.tblUnit u2  on 
    (
        u2.fkUnitGroupID = u.pkUnitID 
        and 
        u.ynPhyUnit = 0
    )   
    or
    (
        u2.pkUnitID in (u.pkUnitID, ug.fkUnitPhisicallID) 
        and 
        u2.ynPhyUnit = 1
    )
where u.pkUnitId = 3806
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this with best results in execution plan, I am reviewing with other values:

```
SELECT u2.fkPropertyID, u2.pkUnitId, u2.UnitCode, u2.fkUnitViewID, 
           u2.fkFloorPlanID, u2.fkCalendarTypeID
FROM tblUnit                u 
left join dbo.tblUnitGroup ug  ON ug.fkUnitLogicalID = u.pkUnitID
outer apply
(
 select uu2.fkPropertyID, uu2.pkUnitId, uu2.UnitCode, 
        uu2.fkUnitViewID, uu2.fkFloorPlanID, uu2.fkCalendarTypeID
 from dbo.tblUnit uu2 
 where ( ((uu2.fkUnitGroupID = u.pkUnitID) and (u.ynPhyUnit = 0))
         or
         ((uu2.pkUnitID = u.pkUnitID) and (uu2.ynPhyUnit = 1)) )
       or
       ( (uu2.pkUnitId = ug.fkUnitPhisicallID) and (uu2.ynPhyUnit = 1) )
) as u2
where u.pkUnitId = 3806
```